# Customize the user creation process in liferay portal

Tags: liferay

As we know, Liferay has the inbuilt functionality for creating users. But i want to have an workflow for creating users which involves approval process. I mean, user will be created by admin but it should be approved by another authorized person, then only the user account will be active.

Is there any way to customize the user creation process in Liferay?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have 3 methods to achieve it someway:

1. Implement ModelListener interface over the User model entity of
   Liferay Portal.
2. Extend ServiceWrapper to modify functionality
3. Configure a Workflow in the control panel (Kaleo portlet on the EE version). Not 100% sure about
   this last one.

The first two methods would include developing what is called a Liferay Hook.
This is described in the Liferay Wiki and Documentation

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Model Listener hook to intercept the user creation process and deactivate the newly created user. Check [this link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-ModelListeners) for more information on model listeners in Liferay.

Then you could use the Liferay permissioning system to assign Deactivate/Restore rights to a certain role.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TLCG Information Server at http://www.thelondonconsulting.com/products/information-server . You can use BPM to create a process with human tasks and then upload user to LDAP. Liferay will import only created users in LDAP.